# How to get an ID from Ref in fauna?

Tags: faunadb

I'm fetching documents from faunadb and I would like their ID to be in the payload that I send to the client.

This is how I fetch the documents and return their data as a collection

```js
serverClient.query(
  q.Map(
    q.Paginate(q.Documents(q.Collection('Portfolio')), { size: 999999 }),
      q.Lambda(x => q.Get(x))
    )
  )
  .then((ret) => ret.data.map(x => ({ ...x.data, _id: x.ref })))
```

Now `_id` is a Ref. Looking like this when I log it to the console:

```
Ref(Collection("Portfolio"), "266565241615155713")
```

And like this when JSON Stringifying it:

```
{"@ref":{"id":"266565241615155713","collection":{"@ref":{"id":"Portfolio","collection":{"@ref":{"id":"collections"}}}}}}
```

I basically need to get the ID `266565241615155713` from that Ref. How can I do that?
I tried `x.ref['@ref'].id` but `@ref` is undefined.
[The documentation](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/ref) did not help me here

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to get the id with **ref.id** before it's transformed to Json which I believe is the case where you are currently doing: '_id: x.ref', so just replace that with _id: x.ref.id should be fine.

Once you have transformed it to Json, you will have to do jsonRef.['@ref'].id

Comment: ‍♂️ duh - should've tried it myself. Works beautifully. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can also return an array with the `id` and the expanded `ref`, with that, you are not committing to the json format (that could change in the future). You can achieve that, updating your lambda to `Lambda(x => [ Select('id', x), Get(x) ])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `match()` function to find the document whose id you need and then call the `id()` method on the "ref" attribute of the JSON returned. For example, say I want to get the ref id of a user on a "User" collection it'd be as follows:

```py
user = client.query(q.get(q.match(q.index("user_by_name"), "Paul")))
```

This would return a JSON containing a Ref object, with the key of `["ref"]`, which holds the id we need. From this we can retrieve the id using the `id()` function as follows:

```py
print(user["ref"].id())
```

Which would print the id to the console. You can of course pass this into a different query as you might want to.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Doc](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/cookbook/basics/documents/reference?lang=javascript) here how you can get the id from the `Ref`

```js
client.query(
  q.Let(
    {
      doc: q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection("users"), "1")),
    },
    {
      "id": q.Select(["ref", "id"], q.Var("doc")),
    }
  )
)
```